# Cosolidating large excel files, cant go around buffer overflow

Tags: vba, excel, large-files, buffer-overflow

I am trying to consolidate multiple large excel files into one single file using the following code

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim Country As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    k = 2
    For i = 1 To 50
        Windows("Try2").Activate
        Country = Worksheets("Names").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:path\" & Country & " "
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Activate
        finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Workbooks(Country).Sheets("Main").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10000, 64)).Copy
        Workbooks("Try2").Sheets("Output").Activate
        Workbooks("Try2").Sheets("Output").Cells(k, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(k + 10000, 1)) = Country
        finalrow2 = 10002 + k
        k = finalrow2 + 1
        Workbooks(Country).Sheets("Main").Activate
        Workbooks(Country).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

However after consolidating 2-3 files excel it is throwing buffer overflow error. We have around 50 files. I am trying to figure out if this is just a problem with excel unable to handle large files or there is something wrong with my code. Is there any way to guide excel to handle larger files sizes?

Comment: Try using something along these lines instead of the copy pastespecial  `application.Workbooks(2).ActiveSheet.range("a1:c5").value=application.Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet.range("a1:c5").value`

Comment: I am sorry i am unable to wrap my head around your suggestion. Apologies

Comment: you also declared your variables as integers, I'm not sure on how many rows you are going to in the consolidations but if they exceed the  32767 limit of integers in excel it will return an overflow error, try to declare them as a 'long'

Comment: I usually try to refrain from copying and take over data only, fastest and easiest for me is to read the whole table into an array (if the table is very big, I take not .Value but .Value2 which means it only takes the raw value and is significantly faster. Printing it back to a sheet and then formatting is quite fast too. Copying also hahs the disadvantage of copying all kinds of sometimes 'funny' formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite along the lines of good coding practice Werff already explained to you, you could try this other (commented) code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim outputSht As Worksheet '<--| declare a variable to set your "output" sheet to
    Dim countryData As Variant, countryNames As Variant '<--| declare arrays to store "country names" and "country data" in
    Dim country As Variant '<-- "countries" looping variable

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual '<-- disable calculations
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False '<-- disable screen updating


    With Workbooks("Try").Worksheets("Names") '<--| reference "country names" worksheet
        countryNames = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value) '<--| store country names in column "A" from row 1 down to last not empty row
    End With

    Set outputSht = Workbooks("Try").Worksheets("Output") '<--| set "output" worksheet
    For Each country In countryNames '<-- loop through countries stored in 'countryNames'

        With Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:path\" & Country).Sheets("Main") '<--| open current country workbook and reference its "Main" sheet
            countryData = .Range("BL1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value '<--| store current country data in 'countryData' array
            .Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False '<--| close current country workbook
        End With

        With outputSht '<--| reference output sheet
            With .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(countryData, 1)) '<--|reference its column A range from first empty cell after last not empty cell down to as many rows as current country array has
                .Value = country '<--| write current country name in referenced range
                .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 64).Value = countryData '<--| write country data array content from column B rightwards
            End With
        End With
    Next country

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

since it uses arrays to store data, it suffers from the arrays maximum size limitation to 65536 rows. If your "countries" workbooks "Main" sheets have more rows than such a limit then different pasting values techniques must be adopted  (like between range values)

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things here that could be throwing your macro off.

First, you're declaring `i`, `j`, and `k` as the 'integer' data type; problem with that is that the largest possible value an integer can hold is 32,767. If you go above that, you're going to get a buffer overflow.

Second, you're declaring variables that you don't use, and not declaring variables that you do use. As far as I can see, `j` isn't used anywhere in the code, but `finalrow` and `finalrow2` are used but aren't declared anywhere.

I would suggest you replace your `integer` data types that could go very high with `long` data types (long integer). You might also want to use more descriptive names for your integers to make your code easier to read:

```
Dim iCycler as integer
Dim kStart as long
Dim FinalRow as Long
Dim FinalRow2 as Long
```

Run through that and see what you get.

EDITED TO ADD:

Here is a complete process that should suit you:

```
Sub Duplicator()

    'Define the source file, sheet, and range
    Dim wbkSource As Workbook
    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range
    'Define the target file, sheet and range
    Dim wbkTarget As Workbook
    Dim shtTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    'Define the sheet with the list of countries
    Dim shtControl As Worksheet
    'Prepare control integers
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    'Define the target file as the active workbook
    Set wbkTarget = ActiveWorkbook
    Set shtTarget = wbkSource.Sheets("Output")
    Set rngTarget = shtTarget.Range("A2")
    Set shtControl = wbkTarget.Sheets("Names")

    'Loop through the list
    For iLoop = 1 To 50
        'Open the source file and assign it to a variable.
        Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\path\" & shtControl.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value)
        'Assign the source sheet
        Set shtSource = wbkSource.Sheets("Main")
        'Find the last row of data
        lLastRow = shtSource.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Use the last row to build a source range variable
        Set rngSource = shtSource.Range("A1", "BL" & lLastRow)
        'Check that there is space for the copy. If there is not, create a new sheet for the new data
        If rngTarget.Row + lLastRow > shtTarget.Rows.Count Then
            Set shtTarget = wbkTarget.Sheets.Add
            shtTarget.Name = "Output 2"
            Set rngTarget = shtTarget.Range("A2")
        End If
        'Use the size of rngSource to define the size of the target range
        Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, rngSource.Columns.Count)
        'Duplicate the values over
        rngTarget.Value = rngSource.Value
        'Prepare the target range for the next loop
        Set rngTarget = shtTarget.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        'Close the source file
        wbkSource.Close False
    Next iLoop
End Sub
```

By declaring and using variables throughout, the code should be easier both to write and to read. It should also run quicker, since it's using the `range1.value = range2.value` structure, which bypasses the rather slow clipboard. It also contains a check to make sure that you're not surpassing 1,048,576 rows of data, which would cause a crash.